# I want to make Javascript object dynamic

Tags: javascript, object

Here is Code

```js
var str = "Value1";

var str1 = "Value2";

var obj = {
  [str]: str1
};

console.log(obj);
```

I am getting obj as

```
{
    Value1:"Value2"
}
```

But I want this object as

```
{
    "Value1":"Value 2"
}
```

Can any one explain how it is possible?

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you calling of dynamic?

Comment: The quotes mean NOTHING, it is just how your console is displaying it.  `JSON.stringify(console.log(obj))`

Comment: It's the same in 99% of the use cases. JSON.stringify your object if for some reason you need a string showing quoted object keys.

Comment: I wana get Value1 in double quotes too dynamic means I want dynamic index too in double quotes

Comment: Semantically there's no difference (e.g. try just pasting `console.log({"Value1":"Value 2"})` directly into your console and you'll see the same result).

Comment: Again it it just how your console displays it....

Comment: Why? If it is to send to a database or json file, stringify it. If it is to use in code, there is no difference. It all depends on which browser you use how the object will be shown. So can you explain why the quotes matter to you?

Comment: var param = Dashboards.getParameterValue("p_legends_name");

var str=String(param[1]);

this.chartDefinition.colorMap ={
 [str]: 'red'
};
I want to run it on Pentaho CDE and Pentaho Hierarchy accepting object in this way that's why I need it

Comment: Do you have an error or something? That code should work unless for some weird reason getParameterValue returns you `'"Value1"'` instead of `"Value1"` or `'Value1'`.

Comment: @WaleedAli You have an object..... Again it is just a display issue. Under the hood `var x = { "foo" : "bar" }, y = { 'foo' : 'bar'}, z = { foo : "bar"}` are the same thing. You are not dealing with JSON so it should make no difference.

Comment: I am giving static value in object and its working fine but when I make it dynamic it does not show any result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) and the OP is unable to describe the real issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At first your code: `var obj = {["Value1"]: "Value2"};` is wrong. You have to write:
`var obj = {"Value1": "Value2"};` or `var obj = {Value1: "Value2"};`.

And then if I understood you correctly: in your comment you wrote:

> *I wana get Value1 in double quotes too dynamic means I want dynamic index too in double quotes*

**The answer:**

Object `{Value1:"Value2"}` is the same like `{"Value1":"Value2"}`. The difference is to see in displaying (spelling, writing) of your code only.

For example you will not see the difference if you execute following code:

```js
var myObj1 = {"Value1":"Value2"};
var myObj2 = {Value1:"Value2"};

console.log(myObj1.Value1); //Value2
console.log(myObj2.Value1); //Value2

console.log(myObj1["Value1"]); //Value2
console.log(myObj2["Value1"]); //Value2

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj1)); //{"Value1":"Value2"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj2)); //{"Value1":"Value2"}
```